# CMakeLists Multiple Source Files

Tags: c, cmake, clion

Hi I have a directory called `"Question 1"` with the following structure:

```
.idea 
cmake-build-debug
1a.c
1b.c
1c.c
CMakeLists.txt
```

`.idea and cmake-build-debug` are folders containing other data which come default when creating a project (I'm using CLion), the other 3 are my source files i.e. `1a.c, 1b.c, 1c.c`. My `CMakeLists.txt` file contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(CLion)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES 1b.c)
add_executable(CLion ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

As you can imagine per above I can only run the source file `1b.c`. How do I edit `CMakeLists.txt` so that I can build an executable for each source file?

Comment: Are the three sources all contributing to the same program, or are they each for their own program?  I would have guessed the former, but your later comments seem to suggest the latter.

Comment: Do you want to create executables for other source files? Just add more `add_executable` calls.

Comment: ... also note that the first parameter to `add_executable` is the name of the executable to create.  That can be the same as the name of the project, as in your example, but it does not by any means have to be.

Comment: @JohnBollinger They are 3 separate programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `add_executable()` call in your `CMakeLists.txt` specifies a separate executable to build.  Since you want three executables, you need three such calls.

Furthermore, each executable needs a different name.  In the case where each executable is built from its own source file, it is conventional for the names of the sources and executables to be related.  In particular, I would expect the executable built from `1b.c` to be named `1b`.

Putting that together, here's one way to do it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(CLion)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(1a 1a.c)
add_executable(1b 1b.c)
add_executable(1c 1c.c)
```

Note that you don't need to use a variable to designate the source files for an executable.  Moreover, if you *want* to use variables then there is nothing special about the variable name `SOURCE_FILES`.  For example, you could needlessly complicate the above example by introducing per-target source variables, like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(CLion)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCES_1A 1a.c)
set(SOURCES_1B 1b.c)
set(SOURCES_1C 1c.c)

add_executable(1a ${SOURCES_1A})
add_executable(1b ${SOURCES_1B})
add_executable(1c ${SOURCES_1C})
```

Comment: Cheers helps a lot!